# Rails server gives out an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I am running the command `"rails server"`, but when it launches, it gives out the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "app_name" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "app_name"
```

I cant figure out, what might be the problem, here is my GemFile:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: app_name
  password: password
```

I am running Rails on Ubuntu with posgresql db.

Comment: Can you log into using psql as app_name/password? I'm guessing you can't

Comment: nope, the hole thing screwed up (I am new to rails and especially postgresql). any way out?

Comment: How did you set up your postgres database? Did you create this user already?

Comment: I logged into the database (sudo -u postgres psql); then I've created the user (CREATE USER app_name WITH PASSWORD 'password';). Then I've created the database (CREATE DATABASE app_development OWNER app_name;);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I hope that's not really your "GemFile", I hope it's your `config/database.yml` file.

Second, I feel a bit silly doing this, because the error you've shown seems really clear to me, but maybe you just need the error rephrased. You have configured your app to login to your postgresql database using a username of `app_name` and a password of `password`. Those credentials are not valid for your database.

Comment: 1) You are right, I've made a typo; 2) You mean, that the user name and the password are not matching the ones for the database?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you don't have a postgres user account set up.

Run this command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

This will log you into postgres as the postgres super user. You are then going to want to [create a user](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html)

```
CREATE ROLE my_app PASSWORD 'password' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;
```

Create DB is the important permission. The rest shouldn't really matter, see documentation for more information.

Then in your database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_app_development
  pool: 5
  username: my_app
  password: password    
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

Then you should be able to run `rake db:create` to create the my_app_development database via the my_app user.

Comment: Well, I try to run rake db:create and it gives me out this error="Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"app_development", "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"app_name", "password"=>"password"}"; do you know what that means?

Comment: That's the generic response when creation fails. There may be more information in the stack trace that points to what exactly went wrong. The only thing from the final error that it might be is the port is missing.